# MPI - each slave receives same data

Tags: mpi

I have problem with receiving data for slaves and I don't know where is problem. I send different data for each slave, but all slaves receive same. Here is my code

```
for (int i = 1; i < slavesCounter; i++){
   data = x[cnt]; // x is vector of struct

MPI_Pack(&data.a, 1, MPI_INT, buffer, LENGTH, &position,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Pack(&data.b, 1, MPI_INT, buffer, LENGTH, &position,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

 MPI_Send (buffer, position, MPI_PACKED, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      cnt++;
    }
```

here is slave part

```
while(true){
position = 0; 
MPI_Recv(buffer, LENGTH, MPI_PACKED, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      MPI_Unpack(buffer, LENGTH, &position, &x, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Unpack(buffer, LENGTH, &position, &y, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


 cout << x << " " << y << endl;

    }
```

When I print received data, all slaves get same data. Could someone help me, where could be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to reset `position` at the beginning of each iteration.

So you send a buffer that gets bigger and bigger but you did not notice it because you only unpack the first two integers.